# Login Modal With No Page Redirect ASP.Net MVC Can't Authenticate In A Partial View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authentication

After logging in successfully in the Account Controller I try to render _LoginPartial.cshtml to switch the text in my navbar from "Log In" to "Log Out" ("log out" is in a form and has a antiprivacy token. I'm calling RenderRazorViewToString to call the partial view and pass it to my ajax response, but 'Request.Isauthenticated' is always false in the partial view, so the text never changes to "Log Off"
Maybe I'm just not understanding how authentication works? or maybe it has something to do with my antiforgerytoken from the Ajax call.

All code is below.

AccountController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LoginJson(string email, string password, bool rememberme)
    {
        ..code here left blank

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync
                     (userName, password, rememberme, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return Json(new { error = false, message = RenderRazorViewToString("_LoginPartial", null) });

            ..code here left blank
        }
    }

    private string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (model != null)
            ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                     viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                         ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```html
//Request.IsAuthenticated is false when calling it from RenderRazorViewToString
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm"})) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Yoga Band!", "Create", "YogaSpace")</li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("User", "UserProfile", "Account")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Profiles", "Edit", "Student")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Yoga Spaces", "Index", "YogaSpace")</li>
      <li><a href="#">Schedules</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Invite Friends!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
  </li>
</ul>
} } else {
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Yoga Space!", "Create", "YogaSpace")</li>
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: new { returnUrl = Request.RawUrl }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
</ul>
}
```

Here is the ajax call I'm making to hit the controller to login

```js
LoginIntoStd: function(email, password, rememberme, antiForgeryToken,
  successCallback, failureCallback) {
  var data = {
    "__RequestVerificationToken": antiForgeryToken,
    "email": email,
    "password": password,
    "rememberme": rememberme
  };
  $.ajax({
      url: "/Account/LoginJson",
      type: "POST",
      data: data
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      if (response.error) {
        failureCallback(response.message);
      } else {
        successCallback(response.message);
      }
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      failureCallback(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

Here is the successfull callback method

```js
loginSuccess: function(message) {
  // close the modal
  $('#ModalLogin').modal('hide');
  // change the navbar items to show 'log out'
  $('#loginPartial').replaceWith(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really test the code, but my first guess is that it has something to do with the flow, I think the `Request` Object and it's `IsAuthenticated` property are generated during the request itself, which happens before the sign in is actually processed. I'd advise you to do the following, it will clean up your code a bit also:

Separate the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` into two files. One is the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` and will contain the code for non-authorised only (the "else"-block). Create another file called `_LogoutPartial.cshtml` where you put in only the content for the authorised users.

In your `switch` of the `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` result, you return either the one partial, or the other.

Alternatively, you could try to check `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` instead of `Request.IsAuthenticated` in your view, it might be set correctly in time, but this is only a guess.

Comment: hi Thomas, thanks for the response. I tried replacing 'Request.Isauthenticated' with 'User.Identity.IsAuthenticated' but that didn't seem to do anything. I also tried your other option and pulled out all the code from the "if" block and stuck it into a partial view. Then I just rendered the partial view in the switch statement and that works great and the "Log Out" gets displayed, BUT the antiforgerytoken in the partial view throws an error when I try and log out. Any thoughts!?

Comment: @user1186050 Sorry I'm not very experienced with the antiforgerytoken, but it seems that a token generated in your Ajax call is not valid anymore when checked with the page context generated before. Not sure if helpful, but see this: http://blog.rohit-lakhanpal.info/2013/10/validating-anti-forgery-tokens-over.html or search for "antiforgerytoken ajax", many people seem to have problems with that.